# How do I fix a request timeout?

Tags: express, nginx, server, request, timeout

I have an api up using nginx. The same request is made by the same app in many clients. Everything works fine in all of them except by one specific. It returns an html with timeout error from nginx. Could be ip-related? The headers are all the same.

The problematic client is in a vpn, I don't know if it is important.

How can I fix it?